# How to paste value of a sheet using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have always used following to make a sheet to contain only values:

```
Sheets("NameOfTheTab").Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:= xlPasteValues
```

But this is not safe, if someone/event change the selection, the program runs into random behaviour. How can can I get rid of this pattern?

Comment: Only an event can cause confusion here, as user interaction with your workbook is disabled while your macro is running.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, you can avoid selecting the cells, just directly copy them:

```
Sheets("NameOfTheTab").Activate
Cells.Copy
Cells(1,1).PasteSpecial Paste:= xlPasteValues
```

Although this might not be the fastest way, depending on your sheet/actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should always avoid using select method, beacuse it is not reliable. The sub below is a sample to copy data from a worksheet and paste only values to another one. This sample sub assumes you are running this macro from your target workbook if not change `ThisWorkbook` to your target workbook.

```
Sub copy_paste_only_values()
'will copy all cells in your tab that contain data
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NameOfTheTab").Cells.Copy
'will paste only values to your target worksheet
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NameOfTheTargetTab").Range("A1")._
PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
'empty the clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```